# SQL - querying Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) with missing attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-attribute-value

I have database that is equivalent to following table:

```
id |  foo |  bar
---+------+-----
 1 |    5 |    6
 2 |    7 | NULL
```

but, unfortunately, implemented as Entity-Attribute-Value:

```
CREATE TABLE obj(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE attrdef(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(4));
CREATE TABLE attr(obj_id INTEGER NOT NULL, attrdef_id INTEGER NOT NULL, value INTEGER NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO obj VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO obj VALUES(2);

INSERT INTO attrdef VALUES(3, 'foo');
INSERT INTO attrdef VALUES(4, 'bar');

INSERT INTO attr VALUES(1,3,5);
INSERT INTO attr VALUES(1,4,6);
INSERT INTO attr VALUES(2,3,7);
```

I need to query that database to get data in "proper" form - like in example table. I have tried:

```
SELECT obj.id, foo.value, bar.value
FROM obj 
LEFT JOIN attr foo ON (obj.id = foo.obj_id)
LEFT JOIN attrdef foo_def ON (foo.attrdef_id = foo_def.id)
LEFT JOIN attr bar ON (obj.id = bar.obj_id)
LEFT JOIN attrdef bar_def ON (bar.attrdef_id = bar_def.id)
WHERE foo_def.name = 'foo' AND bar_def.name = 'bar';
```

but the second row is missing:

```
id |  foo |  bar
---+------+-----
 1 |    5 |    6
```

and

```
SELECT obj.id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN name='foo' THEN value ELSE NULL END) foo,
    MAX(CASE WHEN name='bar' THEN value ELSE NULL END) bar
FROM obj LEFT JOIN attr ON (obj.id = attr.obj_id)
LEFT JOIN attrdef ON (attr.attrdef_id = attrdef.id)
GROUP BY obj.id;
```

which gives correct result:

```
id |  foo |  bar
---+------+-----
 1 |    5 |    6
 2 |    7 | NULL
```

but performance of this query is unacceptable.

I'd like standard SQL query, but good MySQL-specific solution would be appreciated.

Comment: If performance is unacceptable drop EAV model... Put your data into json or any format that holds unstructured data and apply indexing.

Comment: I mean second version of my query has unacceptable performance. I'd like to drop EAV model, but that's beyond my control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to move the conditions to the `on` clauses:

```
SELECT obj.id, foo.value, bar.value
FROM obj LEFT JOIN
     attr foo
     ON obj.id = foo.obj_id LEFT JOIN
     attrdef foo_def
     ON foo.attrdef_id = foo_def.id AND foo_def.name = 'foo' LEFT JOIN
     attr bar
     ON obj.id = bar.obj_id LEFT JOIN
     attrdef bar_def
     ON bar.attrdef_id = bar_def.id AND bar_def.name = 'bar';
```

For the aggregation method, I would go with:

```
SELECT obj.id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'foo' THEN value END) foo,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'bar' THEN value END) bar
FROM obj LEFT JOIN
     attr
     ON obj.id = attr.obj_id LEFT JOIN
     attrdef
     ON attr.attrdef_id = attrdef.id
WHERE name IN ('foo', 'bar')
GROUP BY obj.id;
```

The `left join`s might not be necessary in this case (depending on the distribution of missing values).  In any case, if you start looking at more and more attributes, the `JOIN` method takes longer and longer.  The `GROUP BY` method has about the same performance.

EDIT:

The correct query is:

```
SELECT obj.id, foo.value, bar.value
FROM obj LEFT JOIN
     (attr foo JOIN
      attrdef foo_def
      ON foo.attrdef_id = foo_def.id AND foo_def.name = 'foo'
     )
     ON obj.id = foo.obj_id LEFT JOIN
     (attr bar JOIN
      attrdef bar_def
      ON bar.attrdef_id = bar_def.id AND bar_def.name = 'bar'
     )
     ON obj.id = bar.obj_id ;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac339/5) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: First query yields 5 rows instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this in the where caluse:

```
AND bar_def.name = 'bar';
```

You convert that left join on bar_def to an inner join. Same thing with the condition you put on Foo_def.